# CakePHP: How can I use a “OR” operation when building queries with find method

Tags: cakephp

I want to do free search on 5 columns in my view. I have following 5 columns
1. Category
2. Type
3. Reference
4. Url

and now if users enter this data
CATEGORY == file , TYPE == technical , REFERENCE == umair , URL == files/umair.jpg

I want to search all rows from databse in which there exists a cateogry "file" in any row of column one and type " technical" in any row of column and so on i am trying to Apply "OR" condition but its giving errors.

Here is my query :

```
$this->set('Grades', $this->Grade->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Grade.category'=>$category,'Grade.type'=>$type,'Grade.reference'=>$reference,'Grade.url'=>$url))));
```

THis query is returning Just one row which contains having category == file AND type== technical and reference == umair and url == files/umair.jpg but i want it should return all rows where category == file OR type == technical OR reference == umair OR url == files/umair.jpg

Answer (score 4):

You need to use OR as the condition type. Cake will use AND by default

```
$conditions = array(
    'OR' => array(
        'Grade.category'=>$category,
        'Grade.type'=>$type,
        'Grade.reference'=>$reference,
        'Grade.url'=>$url
    )
)
```

Comment: $conditions = array(
    'OR' => array(
        'Grade.category'=>$category,
        'Grade.type'=>$type,
        'Grade.reference'=>$reference,
        'Grade.url'=>$url
    )
);

$this->set('Grades', $this->Grade->find('all', $conditions);  


it is giving internal error on view its not working

Comment: My Search Function IN CONTROLLER:

`public function search() 
 {
  
  if ($this->request->is('post')) 
  {
   $category  = $this->request->data['Grade']['category'];
   $type      = $this->request->data['Grade']['type'];
   
   
   $conditions = array(
     'OR' => array(
      'Grade.category'=>$category,
      'Grade.type'=>$type)
        );
        
   $this->set('Grades', $this->Grade->find('all', $conditions);     
   
  }
 
 }`

Comment: `$this->Grade->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions))`. Also, you've not specified what error you are getting

Comment: i am doing the sam when i click on search button then despite of giving me view it says an ENTERNAL error has occure infact it is even not goin on Search page as well when i just check it with and condition it goes on search page when i clik ok search files button then it shows a search page then search data i have layout that in upper portion of page i am taking data from users then in lower part of same page when i click on search button it shows results

Comment: When i comment this line in my Search Function of COntroller then it goes on search page

$this->set('Grades', $this->Grade->find( 'all', array('conditions' => $conditions));

Comment: Enable debug leve of 2 and quote the actual error message, or get it from the error log and put it in here